# How to generated detailed code coverage report with xdebug?

Tags: php, xdebug, php-7, phpunit

I'm using PHPUnit 8.0.4 and my report looks like this:

```
  Classes:  0.00% (0/1)
  Methods: 37.50% (9/24)
  Lines:   55.91% (123/220)
```

I'm running the command with the parameters shown below:

`phpunit --coverage-html build/coverage-report --configuration phpunit.xml --testsuite query-parser`

These are my logging settings in phpunit.xml:

```
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html" target="./tmp/report" lowUpperBound="35"
             highLowerBound="70"/>
        <log type="coverage-clover" target="./tmp/coverage.xml"/>
        <log type="coverage-php" target="./tmp/coverage.serialized"/>
        <log type="coverage-text" target="php://stdout" showUncoveredFiles="false"/>
        <log type="junit" target="./tmp/logfile.xml"/>
        <log type="testdox-html" target="./tmp/testdox.html"/>
        <log type="testdox-text" target="./tmp/testdox.txt"/>
    </logging>
```

I would like to see which lines and methods weren't covered in order to write the other tests to have a 100% code coverage.

This is my html report
[image]

Comment: this feels very unclear to me .. could be just me though ..

Comment: What is unclear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to create code coverage reports in various formats but only look at the plain text one (which is useless, IMO). Open `./tmp/report/index.html` to see the HTML report.